# Interface, abstract class or another approach java

Tags: java

I have objects Res1 and Res2.

```
public class Res1 {
    public String foo1;
    public String foo2;
}   

public class Res2 {
    public String foo3;
    public String foo4
}
```

I also have an object `Response`

```
public class Response {
    public ResMsg res;
    public String code;
    public String error;
}
```

`Res1` and `Res2` need to be of type `ResMsg`.

Should I create an empty abstract class

```
public abstract class ResMsg {

}
```

and have both `Res1` and `Res2` extend this class, or 
should I create an empty interface and then
have them implement this interface.

Having an empty interface or an abstract class seems like an odd thing.
What is the best way to do this?

**Edit**

I am working on a web service that is passing data from one web service to another. In order to better troubleshoot end to end issues I want to create a common `Response` that will encapsulate responses like `Res1` and `Res2` (original responses that I am getting from the back-end), and add fields `code` and `error`.

Comment: It's the OOP way to do it, so feel free. Use an abstract class if you want to define some methods or behavior in `ResMsg`, otherwise just use an interface. Also depends on the structure you want.

Comment: Can you tell exactly what you want to do with ResMsg since you show only some classes with public properties which doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @jonasnas I added more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create an abstract class only if you want that class to have methods that will be reused by the classes that extends it. If you just want to say that a class belongs to a certain type, I think the use of an interface is more appropriate. This is what we call "tag interface" http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TagInterface

Answer (score 0):

As in your question, Res1 and Res2 need to be type ResMsg, which suggests Res1, Res2 should have something in common.

But from your class definition of Res1, Res2, they just have different fields and nothing in common.

Whether to use interface or not is based on how you want the Response object to be used.

In my opinion, there will be an interface ResMsg, which defines public api, Res1 and Res2 can directly implement the interface. And if Res1 and Res2 have some common logics, you can have an abstract class, such as AbstractResMsg, to implement the common logics. Res1, Res2 can extend the abstract class and implement the interface.

Comment: They don't have anything in common. I added more information to my question.

Comment: @gumenimeda If they have nothing in common, why not just declare both of them in Response. There's no meaning for ResMsg, since the client need to treat Res1, Res2 in different ways.